Custom role for static web app with Azure AD B2C not working
I have tried to build this with a B2C flow but not getting the roles back. My use-case is to use the company name instead for getting the roles. So i have used this tutorial but only getting the roles "anonymous" and "authenticated" on the web-page. I have changed the function from the tutorial to go for companyname:
const fetch = require('node-fetch').default;
const roleGroupMap = {
    'CXL': 'company'
};
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const user = req.body || {};
    const roles = [];
    const company = await getUserCompany(user.accessToken);        
    for (const [role, companyMap] of Object.entries(roleGroupMap)) {
        if (company === companyMap) {
            roles.push(role);
        }
    }
    context.res.json({
        roles
    });
}
async function getUserCompany(bearerToken) {
    const url = new URL('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me');
    url.searchParams.append('$select', 'companyName');
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
        },
    });
    if (response.status !== 200) {
        return null;
    }
    const graphResponse = await response.json();
    return graphResponse.companyName;
}

And this is my staticwebapp.config.json config file:
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/admin/*",
            "allowedRoles": [ "company" ]
        },
        {
            "route": "/authenticated/*",
            "allowedRoles": [ "authenticated" ]
        }
    ],
    "auth": {
     "rolesSource": "/api/GetRoles",
    "identityProviders": {
      "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
        "aadb2c": {
          "registration": {
            "clientIdSettingName": "AADB2C_PROVIDER_CLIENT_ID",
            "clientCredential": {
              "clientSecretSettingName": "AADB2C_PROVIDER_CLIENT_SECRET"
            },
            "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
              "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_dev_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"
            }
          },
          "login": {
        "nameClaimType": "emails",
        "loginParameters": [
          "resource=https://graph.microsoft.com"
        ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "globalHeaders": {
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
}

See the output after the login where you see that it isn't working: screenshot after authentication
As written in the question here, this should work also with B2C and I think I have configured everything correct but it isn't working.
Any hints would be highly appreciated or if you need more details please write it here.
Thanks,
Michael

Can you check this. Azure AD B2C does not currently support appRole.  you can use Azure AD-based authentication to grant appRole because Azure AD supports appRole.

Thank you for your feedback. We know that AAD supports this, but we have to go with B2C. We will use a workaround for now with Conditional access policies to get some blocking.
